# Zero (0 ) Database Result in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

In view->new_entry.php

```
 <?=form_open(base_url().'home/insert_entry/')?>
    <p>Title: <?=form_input('title')?></p>
    <p>Content: <?=form_textarea('content')?></p>
    <p>Tags: <?=form_input('tags')?> (comma separated)</p>
    <?=form_submit('submit', 'Insert')?>
```

In home/insert_entry:

```
public function insert_entry(){
        login_site();
        $entry = array(
            'permalink'  => permalink($this->input->post('title')),
            'author' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'tags' => $this->input->post('tags')
            );      
        $this->home_model->insert('ads', $entry);

        redirect(base_url());
    }
```

In home_model:

```
public function insert($table, $data){
        return $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    }
```

I am getting all result zero (0) on database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the `affected_rows` if it is >= 1

```
public function insert($table, $data){
  $this->db->insert($table, $data);
  return $this->db->affected_rows() >= 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable profiler in your controller.
eg:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

See if your query is executed and if it's correct...